# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate vs. Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPack

Tags: c#, winforms, powerpack

I have solution in Windows Forms C# and Visual Studio 2013 from the university (dreamspark). When I try to run my solution, I've get an error:

> Error    2    The type or namespace name 'PowerPacks' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.VisualBasic' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I cannot find the reference in reference manager:

[image]

How do I repair that?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb735936.aspx

Comment: @SLaks that is version 9.0.0.0 (most recent version is 12.0.0.0)

Answer (score 9):

Despite the MSDN documentation to the contrary, this seems not to be included in Visual Studio 2013.

[But you can still install it from here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=321343). This is the latest version and works in Visual Studio 2017 as well.

Answer (score -1):

Several websites that alluded to the Microsoft Visual Basic PowerPacks are down. So it seems they are slowly removing compatibility support.

In VS 2013 comes only minimal compatibility pack that no longer contains the Printer object.

It remains only install 3 PowerPacks same as mentioned above.

Remember that VB6 is years in state "until it works", and has been widely announced that the next version of Windows is no longer working.